# How to remove undefined returns in once() function (without changing previous function)

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

I have two snippets of code, they differ in the definition of the add(y) function.  One uses console.log() (The original version) and one is modified to use return.  The second way I can get my prompt to pass, which is...

> Write a function once that accepts a callback as input and returns a function. When the returned function is called the first time, it should call the callback and return that output. If it is called any additional times, instead of calling the callback again it will simply return the output value from the first time it was called.

How can I refactor the first code without modifying add(y) to achieve the desired result that is returned in the second code?

```js
//Challenge 4
function addByX(x) {
  function add(y) {
    console.log(y + x);
  }
  return add;
}

var addByTwo = addByX(2);

// now call addByTwo with an input of 1
//addByTwo(1);
// now call addByTwo with an input of 2
//addByTwo(5);

//Challenge 5
function once(func) {
  var answer;

  function inner(x) {
    if (!answer) {
      answer = func(x);
      return answer;
    } else {
      return answer;
    }
  }
  return inner;
}

var onceFunc = once(addByTwo);

// UNCOMMENT THESE TO TEST YOUR WORK!
console.log(onceFunc(5)); //should log 7
console.log(onceFunc(10)); //should log 7
console.log(onceFunc(9001)); //should log 7
```

SECOND CODE(works)

```js
//Challenge 4
function addByX(x) {
  function add(y) {
    return y + x;
  }
  return add;
}

var addByTwo = addByX(2);

// now call addByTwo with an input of 1
//addByTwo(1);
// now call addByTwo with an input of 2
//addByTwo(5);

//Challenge 5
function once(func) {
  var answer;

  function inner(x) {
    if (!answer) {
      answer = func(x);
      return answer;
    } else {
      return answer;
    }
  }
  return inner;
}

var onceFunc = once(addByTwo);

// UNCOMMENT THESE TO TEST YOUR WORK!
console.log(onceFunc(5)); //should log 7
console.log(onceFunc(10)); //should log 7
console.log(onceFunc(9001)); //should log 7
```

Comment: `undefined` is being logged because your function `add()` function doesn't return anything. It prints the sum instead of returning it.

Comment: @Barmar is right, but I wrote an answer to expand upon his comment and also point out a couple of other items you might want to think about.

Answer (score 0):

We can use closures to capture when the function has been called once. When the flag for `called` is `true` it has already been called, in this case it returns the `value` that was set the first time the function was run. Alternatively if this is the first time the function was run, we set `callback` TO `true` and set `value` to the `cb` function called with the parameter `str`. We return this value in either case.

```js
function string_callback(cb) {
  let called = false,
    value;
  return function(str) {
    if (called) return value;
    called = true;
    value = cb(str);
    return value;
  }
}

let my_func = string_callback((input) => input.toUpperCase());
my_func("hihihih");

console.log(my_func("banana"));
console.log(my_func("banana"));
console.log(my_func("banana"));
```

```html
Write a function once that accepts a callback as input and returns a function. When the returned function is called the first time, it should call the callback and return that output. If it is called any additional times, instead of calling the callback
again it will simply return the output value from the first time it was called.
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend upon what @Barmar wrote in his comment, in the first example your inner 'add' function isn't returning anything so its return value will be undefined.  Therefore, answer remains falsy each time 'inner' is called, and so the captured 'addByTwo' function gets called all three times.  This is why you get the alternating number, which is the addition result logged in 'add' itself, and undefined which is the logged return value. You fix this in your second example by passing back a return value from 'add'.

Now, I did want to point out a couple of things to you that might be helpful.

**1) Your second example will still fail if you pass in -2 the first time you call 'onceFunc'.  Why? Because this statement:**

```
if (!answer) {
```

Checks to see if answer is falsy, which 0 is (-2 + 2).  You can fix this problem by instead checking to see if answer is undefined.

**2) I don't how flexible you need this to be, but by using the 'apply' method on your captured function you don't have to specify arguments for 'inner'.  This means that the function you pass in can accept zero, one, or multiple arguments.**

Here is an example of your code breaking when -2 is passed in (as referenced in item #1):

```js
function addByX(x) {
  function add(y) {
    return y + x;
  }
  return add;
}

var addByTwo = addByX(2);

function once(func) {
  var answer;

  function inner(x) {
    if (!answer) {
      answer = func(x);
      return answer;
    } else {
      return answer;
    }
  }
  return inner;
}

var onceFunc = once(addByTwo);

console.log(onceFunc(-2)); //should log 0
console.log(onceFunc(10)); //should log 0, but it won't
```

And here it is fixed to handle the issue mentioned in #1, and provide the flexibility mentioned in #2:

```js
function addByX(x) {
  function add(y) {
    return y + x;
  }
  return add;
}

function mult(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

var addByTwo = addByX(2);

function once(func) {
  var answer;

  function inner() {
    if(typeof answer === 'undefined') {
      answer = func.apply(null, arguments);
      return answer;
    } else {
      return answer;
    }
  }
  return inner;
}

var onceFunc = once(addByTwo);

console.log(onceFunc(-2)); // should log 0
console.log(onceFunc(10)); // should log 0, this time it will
console.log(onceFunc(9001)); // should log 0, and again it will


// this can also be re-used with a function that accepts multiple parameters (or none)
var onceFuncMult = once(mult);

console.log(onceFuncMult(3, 5)); // 15
console.log(onceFuncMult(8, 5)); // still 15
```

Hope this is helpful and provides a little bit of additional information to help you along.